# Android Layout Margins ScrollView

Tags: android, layout, scrollview

I have this scrollview with Linearlayout inside it and again one linearlayout in it.
I want to display a data in table like format.
I have a listview in which I push data through code using record.xml as a single row in the listview.

I wish to show margins in it. but they are not working. They are showed in eclipse accurately, but not in emulator android 2.3 when deployed.

Help.
Thanks in advance...Awaiting reply...
**record.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:minHeight="50dp" android:gravity="center_vertical" android:background="#D1EFCD">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/serial_no"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="null"
        android:width="100dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:background="#9EC39A"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="null"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:width="100dp" android:background="#9EC39A" android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/wt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="null"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:width="100dp" android:background="#9EC39A" android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dte"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="null"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:width="100dp" android:background="#9EC39A" android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/amt"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="null"
        android:width="100dp" android:background="#9EC39A" android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cust_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="null"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:width="100dp" android:background="#9EC39A" android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="null"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:width="100dp" android:background="#9EC39A" android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"/>

</TableRow>
```

**scrolldata.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical"
android:background="#D1EFCD" >
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_margin="1dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Sr.No."
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Sr.No."
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:width="100dp" android:layout_marginTop="2dp" android:layout_marginLeft="2dp" android:background="#9EC39A" android:gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Item"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="Item"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:width="100dp" android:layout_marginTop="2dp" android:layout_marginLeft="1dp" android:background="#9EC39A" android:gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Weight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="Weight"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:width="100dp" android:layout_marginTop="2dp" android:layout_marginLeft="1dp" android:background="#9EC39A" android:gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="Date"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:width="100dp" android:layout_marginTop="2dp" android:layout_marginLeft="1dp" android:background="#9EC39A" android:gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Amount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="Amount"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:width="100dp" android:layout_marginTop="2dp" android:layout_marginLeft="1dp" android:background="#9EC39A" android:gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/CustomerName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="Customer Name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:width="100dp" android:layout_marginTop="2dp" android:layout_marginLeft="1dp" android:background="#9EC39A" android:gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/RateofInterest"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="Rate of Interest"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:width="100dp" android:layout_marginTop="2dp" android:layout_marginLeft="1dp" android:layout_marginRight="2dp" android:background="#9EC39A" android:gravity="center"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/DataRows"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:divider="#D1EFCD"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp" android:layout_marginBottom="2dp" android:layout_marginLeft="2dp" android:layout_marginRight="2dp" android:layout_marginTop="1dp" android:layout_gravity="center">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>


</HorizontalScrollView>
```

**screenshot from emulator**
[image]

Comment: i suggest "you can use table layout".

Comment: your issue is not quite clear. can you post the screenshot from eclipse to better understand the difference?

Comment: @silentkratos Do you want to center your row data with the titles? Is that it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to center your data rows text in the `TextViews`, just as the  titles are, just add android:gravity="center" in your `TextViews`, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/serial_no"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#9EC39A"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="123"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:width="100dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
    android:background="#9EC39A"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="asf"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:width="100dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/wt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
    android:background="#9EC39A"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="sadasd"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:width="100dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dte"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
    android:background="#9EC39A"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="23"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:width="100dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/amt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
    android:background="#9EC39A"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="null"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:width="100dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/cust_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
    android:background="#9EC39A"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="null"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:width="100dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/rate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
    android:background="#9EC39A"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="null"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:width="100dp" />
```

This will align your data with your titles.